# Why garbage value is returned if any run time error occur?

Tags: c

In C, I found that a garbage value is returned, if a runtime error occurs. But why does a garbage value is returned in this case?

This code will give runtime error. I know why the runtime error occured here. But I want to know why the return value is a garbage value.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int *x;
    *x = 10;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what runtime error occurs?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10248156/ 
this code will give runtime error. I know why the runtime error occured here. But I want to know why the return value is a garbage value. Please help.
@dimm

Comment: Because you don't handle the error and access uninitialized variables, for example `scanf("%d", &value)` you ignore the return value, the function fails to read, `value` is uninitialized and you go `printf("%d\n", value);`.

Comment: If you are getting a runtime error, then how are you determining that you are getting a garbage return value? Are you saying `echo $?` returns garbage after running your program?

Comment: kindly see here: http://postimg.org/image/78cujlucr/
@IskarJarak

Comment: You _really_ should add that you are working on Windows and what compiler you are using to your question (may as well link to that image in the body of the question as well). It's quite important for this question.

Comment: It took > 4 seconds to run that program???

Comment: Actually I am new here. Would you please tell me why this is spam? What type of question should I ask here? thanks in advance. @TomDignan

Comment: @TomDignan What is your reasoning for claiming this is spam? (As opposed to VLQ &c)

Comment: @IskarJarak -- was a mistake, I've since retracted my vote

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That isn't a garbage value, it's the Microsoft Windows error code for a segmentation fault; 0xC0000005 ([STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION is the correct name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588%28d=lightweight,l=en-us,v=PROT.10%29.aspx))

`x` is uninitialised, so it may point outside the memory your program has been given access to by the OS, thus you get an access violation when you de-reference it. On Linux, you would possibly expect to see 139 (SIGSEGV), depending on the OS and compiler.

EDIT: Note that your `main` does not return this value - the process is getting terminated by the OS.

Comment: Note that you can fix this by trapping the exception (or signal in *nix) and return a different value.  I think by default,  an exception like this (or a SIGSEGV in *nix) is forwarded to the exit(.) function with the exception code as the return value.

Comment: That isn't a return value then. The OP needs to read basic programming books.

Comment: @iharob Well, it isn't the return value of his `main`, at least. It's likely the return value of something somewhere (exactly what happens is OS dependent and I don't know Windows all that well). The question could be much improved, but cmd does say `'Process returned... (0xC0000005)` so there is a plausible rationale behind the way he asked his question.

Answer (score 1):

You declare `x` as a pointer, you should not do that if you don't know what a pointer is, your code would work if you make the pointer point to a valid location, to do that you can use the `malloc()` function so, this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int *x;
    x = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (x == NULL)
        return -1;
    /* use x here */
    *x = 10;
    /* release memory */
    free(x);

    return 0;
}
```

in your code, the pointer `x` is not pointing to valid memory so it invokes undefined behavior, and that is the cause of the garbage value.

Pointers are a very important part of the c language, and I think you need to search for a basic tutorial on pointers.

This for example will also be valid

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int *x;
    int  y;

    x  = &y;
    *x = 10;

    printf("%d\n", y);

    return 0;
}
```

the above program will output `10` the pointer `x` is pointing to the address where `y` is stored, so modifying it, will also modify `y`.

Comment: I know this, bro. I think I know pointer well. But what is its relation with garbage value returned? :)